# What is a valley current in a regulator?

Tags: current, voltage-regulator, buck

Can someone explain what is a valley current in a regulator?

Comment: IL(min)= valley of repetitive wave

Answer (score 1):

The valley of the inductor current can also be used to control the current limit of the converter. In this
method, if the valley of the inductor current does not fall below the current limit value, before the next
clock cycle, the MOSFET is not turned on. In this way the cycle is extended until the inductor current
discharges below the valley current limit.